# Django EmailMessage.send() returns 0. What does that mean?

Tags: python, django, email, send

I have the following code in settings.py

```
#EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sender@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 687
```

(I tried using TLS = True and ports using Ports 25, 567, 465, 687 and also tried smtp.gmail.com and other HOSTS from MX records, but I always got a connection refused )

Then I tried using port 687 and commented TLS = True. I get return value "0" for the following code

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', 'me@gmail.com')
email.send()
```

I dont get any mail in my inbox. What does 0 mean ? What am I doing wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Pankaj.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EmailMessage returns 0 if you haven't specified any recipients (to, bcc, cc).  If you have no recipients the EmailMessage.send returns 0.

Also, Googles default smtp port is 587.

Answer (score 0):

If the email sending is configured to fail silently with send_mass_mail. Then an error could result in returning 0 messages sent. In this case, you might want to turn debugging on to see the actual error or configure the sending to fail catastrophically to reveal whats causing the email not be sent. 
You have to check the email backend you are using as different backends will behave differently to input especially where different backends are using for testing and development